# Strange NSPredicate Behaviour?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, core-data

Currently, I have a table view which is populated by video objects depending on the date they were recorded which was taken by using `[nsdate date];` when they were recorded and saved. However, it *is* possible to record multiple videos in one day. I sort them by the date, and when there is more than one video with the same date, it displays the first one recorded on that date, with the most recent ones following in ascending order according to the most recent. I'm not sure why this happens but would like to check if there are more than one videos with the same date recorded, it organizes them by title. In SQL I could do something like:

`ORDER BY DATE_RECORDED, TITLE ASC`

Here is what I am currently doing:

```
AppDelegate *appDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
_managedObjectContext = [appDelegate managedObjectContext];

NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"whosVideo == %@", _currentPerson];
[request setPredicate:predicate];
NSEntityDescription *eval = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Video" inManagedObjectContext:_managedObjectContext];
[request setEntity:eval];

NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor =
[[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"date_recorded"
                            ascending:NO
                             selector:@selector(localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:)];
NSArray *sortDescriptors = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:sortDescriptor, nil];


[request setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptors];

NSError *error = nil;
NSMutableArray *mutableFetchResults = [[_managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:request error:&error] mutableCopy];
if (mutableFetchResults == nil){
    //handle error
}

[self setVideoArray:mutableFetchResults];
[self.tableView reloadData];
```

How would I handle adding a second predicate if there is more than one object recorded on the same date?

Comment: Can't you just add a second sort descriptor and sort by title?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to handle more than one predicate than you have to use NSCompoundPredicate try like this below:-

```
NSPredicate *predicate1 = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"whosVideo == %@", _currentPerson];

NSPredicate *predicate2 = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"whosVideo == %@", _someOther];

  NSArray *subPredicates = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:predicate1, predicate2,nil];

NSPredicate *predicate = [NSCompoundPredicate orPredicateWithSubpredicates:subPredicates];
```